# VBA Multiple loops match conditions

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops, do-while

I apologize if this is a duplicate as I have been searching and haven't found an answer. I am new to VBA and how they structure loops. I am trying to do a search and compare. I need to compare the values in the first row to see if they match the second row and if not then keep moving on to the next row. See my code below (it runs without error just doesn't find any values that do exist as I can search it manually and find them)

This data set could be really large so I want to write this as efficiently as possible and am not sure what loop structures will execute faster. I need to compare the value in column 21 and see if if there is a duplicate value, if there is then I need to see if the values in column 22 of the respective rows are the same and if they are then I want to go to the next row in RowB otherwise if they are not the same value then I want to check the values in row 4 that are both dates and see if they are within 2 months of each other. If they are not keep looking.

```
Dim RowsCount As Integer
Dim ColCount As Integer
RowsCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ColCount = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim RowA As Integer
Dim RowB As Integer
Dim GroupA As Variant
Dim GroupB As Variant
Dim CounterA As Variant
Dim CounterB As Variant
Dim RevDateA As Date
Dim RevDateB As Date
Dim RevDateDiff As Variant

RowA = 2
RowB = 3
Do While RowA <= RowsCount
GroupA = Cells(RowA, 21).Value
CounterA = Cells(RowA, 22).Value
RevDateA = Cells(RowA, 4).Value
    Do While RowB <= RowsCount
    GroupB = Cells(RowB, 21).Value
    CounterB = Cells(RowB, 22).Value
    RevDateB = Cells(RowB, 4).Value
        If GroupA = GroupB Then
            If CounterA = CounterB Then 'go down 1 row in B and repeat
            Else
                If RevDateB - RevDateA < 62 Then
                'highlight row b and move on
                Rows(RowB).Select
                Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "CellFillColorPicker"
                Else
                End If
            End If
        Else 'go down 1 row in B and repeat check
        End If

    RowB = RowB + 1
    Loop

RowA = RowA + 1
Loop
```

Comment: If you're going to have a lot of data (and good practise anyway) then always declare `As Long` instead of `As Integer`.  Integer overflows above ~32,000

Comment: Tim Thanks for that information I will change those variables to As Long.

Comment: You can check for inequal values: `If CounterA <> CounterB Then ...`. Also, you can combine criteria checks using `And` -- `If GroupA = GroupB And CounterA <> CounterB And RevDateB - RevDateA < 62 Then ...`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good way to find row to row dupes

```
Private Sub findit()

Dim bringIn As Variant

bringIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
rowC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = LBound(bringIn, 1) To UBound(bringIn, 1)
    If i = rowC Then
        'nothing
    Else
        If bringIn(i, 1) = bringIn(i + 1, 1) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to handle this? I just see that I would be getting rid of one loop and changing it out for the if statement. I have a 3 condition check that all need conditions need to be met and there will me multiple cases where it will fail after the first case or even the second and the search needs to continue until the end of the sheet. Then it needs to start over and at row 3 and do the check for each and every row below. I know this will take a lot of processing power but it's a complicated check that either takes a computer 10min to do or a person possibly hours.

Comment: Im 100% certain all those criteria can be evaluated in one line. I just provided a cleaner way to check for row to row dupes. IF you're more clear about you're criteria, then i can help, otherwise tinker more :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to speed up your code is not in optimizing loops but changing way how you are accessing Excel data. Always referring `Cells` is much slower than converting ranges to arrays and enumerating arrays instead.

More details here:
[Arrays And Ranges In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

So in your example you can convert `Range` to `Array` first and then enumerate `Array`. Here is your code converted to use array (2 arrays - one for groups and counts in columns U and V, second for dates in column D - Added some comments)

```
Dim RowsCount As Long
Dim RowA As Long
Dim RowB As Long
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim ArrDates As Variant
Dim rangeDefinition As String
Dim rangeDates As String

    RowsCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    rangeDefinition = "U1:V" & RowsCount ' Here define range for groups and counts - columns U and V
    rangeDates = "D1:D" & RowsCount ' Here define range for dates - column D
    Arr = Range(rangeDefinition) ' Here convert groups and counts to array
    ArrDates = Range(rangeDates) ' Here convert dates to array

    RowA = 2
    RowB = 3
    Do While RowA <= RowsCount
        Do While RowB <= RowsCount
            If Arr(RowA, 1) = Arr(RowB, 1) Then ' Compare U column - groups
                If Arr(RowA, 2) = Arr(RowB, 2) Then ' Compare V column - counts -> go down 1 row in B and repeat
                Else
                    If ArrDates(RowB, 1) - ArrDates(RowA, 1) < 62 Then
                    ' Check dates - Column D -> highlight row b and move on
                    Rows(RowB).Select
                    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "CellFillColorPicker"
                    Else
                    End If
                End If
            Else 'go down 1 row in B and repeat check
            End If
        RowB = RowB + 1
        Loop
    RowA = RowA + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: I changed up my code to run it as arrays and the code was only slightly faster. It picked up maybe 0.2-0.3 seconds when executing. I was doing about 1000lines for this example. Is there a way that has better data structure and thus is more robust to future changes?

Comment: Bit shocked by your comment I made benchmark on my test Excel Worksheet with 50k rows and time comparision is 160 ms Array version versus 2 seconds Cells referencing. OK, in my test data I don't have duplicates (just few) but enumeration itself seems to be ~12 times faster.