# VBA, for loop effiency

Tags: vba, excel

all!

I would need to go through over 50k rows of data and delete rows with useless information. 
The current code works but is, unfortunately, all to slow... I tried understanding how it could be made more efficient but there wasn't easily found any concrete examples that I could have understood.

Here is the current code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FIC DATA WITH 3A").Activate
vika = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

r = 2
For i = 2 To vika                  
    If Not Cells(r, "J") > 42369 Then                       
        Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf Cells(r, "I") = "OC" Or Cells(r, "B") = "Sales Doc." Or Cells(r, "B") = "" Then                     
        Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Could you maybe help? Concrete examples are more than appreciated.

Comment: how can it delete correctly when you are looping forward, you need to loop backward when deleting rows, it should be `For i = vika To 2 Step -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete rows, you need to loop backwards `For i = vika To 2 Step -1`.

Also, there's no need to `Activate` "FIC DATA WITH 3A" sheet, in order to run the code on it.

The correct syntax to delete a row is `Rows(i).Delete` , and not `Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete`. If you want to use `EntireRow`, then the syntax is  `Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete` (but doesn't make any sense to me why use it in this situation).

***Code***

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FIC DATA WITH 3A")
    vika = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = vika To 2 Step -1
        If Not Cells(i, "J") > 42369 Or Cells(i, "I") = "OC" Or Cells(i, "B") = "Sales Doc." Or Cells(i, "B") = "" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thank you, the reversing makes so much sense when you think about it!

Answer (score 1):

Shai Rado Answer about looping in reverse order is very important.

To speed up your code you need to convert Excel data into arrays rather than referring Cells in every loop iteration - it runs way faster.

Here is description how to achieve it:
[Arrays And Ranges In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

In your case you would need 2 arrays, one for I and J columns, second for B column.

Comment: You can take a look to another sample - I prepared loop optimization for different code, but rules remains the same - in this Answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509524/vba-multiple-loops-match-conditions/44514759#44514759)